# Connect Two Related TableViewController Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I know the title is a bit ambiguous so let me explain. I have two TableViewControllers, called `MainTableViewController` and `DetailTableViewController`. Moreover, I have multiple arrays created, which in idea are connected through hierarchy:

```
let maincCarChoice = ["Toyota", "Nissan", "Ford"]

let toyotaCarChoice = ["Prius", "Camry", "Etios"]
let nissanCarChoice = ["Altima", "Maxima", "Rogue"]
let fordCarChoice = ["Fusion", "Focus", "Explorer"]
```

I have managed to populate the `MainTableViewController` with the `mainCarChoice` array and implement a `segue` which, when one of the three options is touched, goes to the `DetailTableViewController`. That being said, however, I am unsure as to how to populate the `DetailTableViewController` with the respective array dependent on the user's choice in the `MainTableViewController`. Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: you should have a data mapping from maincCarChoice to toyotaCarChoice, nissanCarChoice etc.. Then based on the mapping, assign the individual arrays.

Comment: Hello, sorry I am new to programming. Would you mind explaining to me what data mapping is, or sending me link to where I can read about it?

Comment: Check with @Moe Abdul-Hameed answer. That is one way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve that is by adding an array of strings member to `DetailTableViewController` like this:

`var vehiclesArray: [String]?`

This array should play as the data source for the table view inside `DetailTableViewController`.

Now, inside `MainTableViewController`:

First, add a dictionary that carries car brands and models:

```
var vehiclesDictionary = ["Toyota" : ["Prius", "Camry", "Etios"],
                          "Nissan" : ["Altima", "Maxima", "Rogue"],
                          "Ford" : ["Fusion", "Focus", "Explorer"]]
```

Then override `prepare` method like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "YourIdentifier" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let selectedVehicle = vehicles[indexPath.row]

            if let nextScene = segue.destination as? DetailTableViewScene {
                nextScene.vehiclesArray = self.vehiclesDictionary[selectedVehicle]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This can also be a dictionary mapping in this class with key as "Toyota" and value as its array. Then this function can be simplified.

Comment: You're right, thank you! I updated the code to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Hey Moe, thanks for your response. What if every car model had a specific property which I wanted to access, what would I do then? For example, after clicking on the Nissan `mainTableViewController`, and once the table populates with the `"Altima, "Maxima", "Rogue"`, I would like to add a the first model year date on the right side of the table view.

Comment: What do you mean by "the first model year date"? and where would you get these information from?